# Laravel 8 : Trying to test a controller method thanks to JSON Get Testing but the route is not found

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-routing

I'm getting this error:

> Expected status code 200 but received 404.
> Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 404.

When I try to call it from my Unit Test:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\Models\Project;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{

    public function testTakePlace()
    {
        $project = Project::factory()->make();

        $response = $this->getJson('controllerUserProject_takePlace', [
            'project_id' => $project->id,
        ]);

        $response
            ->assertStatus(200)
            ->assertJsonPath([
                'project.status' => Project::STATES['TO_BE_REPLIED'],
            ]);
    }
}
```

However, `controllerUserProject_takePlace` is correctly the name I gave to the route. Indeed, here is `/routing/web.php`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\TestConnections;

use App\Http\Controllers\ControllerUserProject;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/controllerUserProject_takePlace/projects/{project_id}', [ControllerUserProject::class, 'takePlace'])->name('controllerUserProject_takePlace');
```

The controller `ControllerUserProject` is correctly defined:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ControllerUserProject extends Controller
{
    public function takePlace(Request $request, $project_id)
    {
        return [
            'project_status' => Project::STATES['TO_BE_REPLIED']
        ];
    }
}
```

Do you know why the use of the route returns 404 (not found)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route url is `'/controllerUserProject_takePlace/projects/{project_id}'` while in the test you are using `'controllerUserProject_takePlace'` hence the 404 error.

Also the second parameter in `getJson()` is array $headers so when you pass `['project_id' => $project->id]` it becomes second parameter taken as $headers.

You need to supply complete url to `getJson('/controllerUserProject_takePlace/projects/' . $project->id);`

or

Since you have already named your route you can use the `route()` helper in `getJson(route('controllerUserProject_takePlace', $project->id));`

Change the url in your test

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use App\Models\Project;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{

    public function testTakePlace()
    {
        $project = Project::factory()->make();

       // $response = $this->getJson('/controllerUserProject_takePlace/projects/' . $project->id);

        //Try using named route

        $response = $this->getJson(route('controllerUserProject_takePlace', $project->id));

        $response
            ->assertStatus(200)
            ->assertJsonPath([
                'project.status' => Project::STATES['TO_BE_REPLIED'],
            ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have still the same issue

Comment: Can you try to visit the route '/controllerUserProject_takePlace/projects/1' (assuming that you have one record for project in db) and see if you are able to visit. If you still get 404 error. Try `php artisan route:clear` to clear route cache if any. See if this works

Comment: Can you see this route listed when you run `php artisan route:list`

Comment: `php artisan route:list` shows indeed: " |        | GET|HEAD | controllerUserProject_takePlace/projects/{project_id} | controllerUserProject_takePlace | App\Http\Controllers\ControllerUserProject@takePlace | web        | "

Comment: Have updated my answer to try using named route in the test. Try it and let me know if it works

Comment: It works! So to use the name, I must have used the function `route()`. This is the sole difference with my OP's code :-)

Comment: `getJson()` second parameter is array $headers, so you need to build the url with $project->id included. If you pass it as second parameter to getJson then it is taken as header and not route parameter. Have updated my answer to use getJson without named route as well